# How does age and employment affect study visa decision?

Tags: canada, student-visa

If someone is unemployed and 40yo, can he get a student visa in Canada?

How does the situation compare, ff he has a,

1. Masters offer
2. PhD offer

I am refused twice. To me, possible reason could be I applied from a 3rd country. What do you think?

Comment: Do you have full funding for the offers? If not, do you have the cash on-hand to support 9 months of tuition + maintenance?

Comment: @mkennedy, yes, I have half cash and the rest of the money is in fixed deposit. Do fixed deposits count? I don't have full funding offer.

Comment: That's fine--if you have a sponsor, that can be harder to get visa approval. I don't know if age/employment will matter. Students are likely to be unemployed, and if you're changing fields by doing a masters or phd, that makes sense.